# Python pandas map dict keys to values

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a csv for input, whose row values I'd like to join into a new field. This new field is a constructed url, which will then be processed by the requests.post() method.

I am constructing my url correctly, but my issue is with the data object that should be passed to requests. How can I have the correct values passed to their proper keys when my dictionary is unordered? If I need to use an ordered dict, how can I properly set it up with my current format?

Here is what I have:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import requests

test_df = pd.read_csv('frame1.csv')

headers = {'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

test_df['FIRST_NAME'] = test_df['FIRST_NAME'].astype(str)
test_df['LAST_NAME'] =  test_df['LAST_NAME'].astype(str)
test_df['ADDRESS_1'] = test_df['ADDRESS_1'].astype(str)
test_df['CITY'] = test_df['CITY'].astype(str)

test_df['req'] = 'site-url.com?' + '&FIRST_NAME=' + test_df['FIRST_NAME'] + '&LAST_NAME=' + \
    test_df['LAST_NAME'] + '&ADDRESS_1=' + test_df['ADDRESS_1'] + '&CITY=' + test_df['CITY']

arr = test_df.values

d = {'FIRST_NAME':test_df['FIRST_NAME'], 'LAST_NAME':test_df['LAST_NAME'],
    'ADDRESS_1':test_df['ADDRESS_1'], 'CITY':test_df['CITY']}

test_df = pd.DataFrame(arr[0:, 0:], columns=d, dtype=np.str)
data = test_df.to_dict()
data = {k: v for k, v in data.items()}

test_df['raw_result'] = test_df['req'].apply(lambda x: requests.post(x, headers=headers,
    data=data).content)

test_df.to_csv('frame1_result.csv')
```

I tried to map values to keys with a dict comprehension, but the assignment of a key like `FIRST_NAME` could end up mapping to values from an arbitrary field like `test_df['CITY']`.

Comment: Please provide some data instead of `frame1.csv`. For better readibility, when constructing strings you should use the `%` operator (or the `format` function). Take a look [here](https://pyformat.info/)

Comment: the data is intuitive: FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME,ADDRESS_1,bob,jones,21 maple st,carla,johnson,42 jump st..

Comment: What rll means is that you will get better responses if you give example before/after DataFrames or pare down your question to the specific lines you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly. However, you can give argument to `to_dict` function e.g.

```
data = test_df.to_dict(orient='records')
```

which will give you output as follows: `[{'FIRST_NAME': ..., 'LAST_NAME': ...}, {'FIRST_NAME': ..., 'LAST_NAME': ...}]` (which will give you a list that has equal length as `test_df`). This might be one possibility to easily map it to a correct row.

Comment: I tried that method, and while it seemingly put the data into a mapped format, when that object was run through the requests.post() method, I got a ValueError: too many values to unpack.